# How to pass values from list to gridview rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, foreach

I want to bind the values from list into gridview rows.

I tried with the below code but it is binding the last value of list on all the monday fields.

Code .aspx:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridActivity" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
         CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="2" BorderStyle="None" 
         BorderColor="#DEBA84" Height="171px" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px" Width="780px">
        <FooterStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
          BackColor="#F7DFB5"></FooterStyle>
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
          HorizontalAlign="Center"></PagerStyle>
        <HeaderStyle Width="10px" Wrap="false" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
          BackColor="SteelBlue"></HeaderStyle>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Activities">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblActivity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ActivityName") %>' CssClass="columnStyle"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monday">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMon" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tuesday">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTue" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Wednesday">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtWed" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Thursday">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtThu" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Friday">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFri" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Saturday">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSat" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sunday">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSun" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Code .cs:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DbConnection.Open();
            gridActivity.DataSource = Application["listActivity"];
            gridActivity.DataBind();
            DbConnection.Close();
        }
        if (Application["mondayValues"] != null)
        {
            //Here I can get all the values
            foreach (string mon in Application["mondayValues"] as List<string>)
            {
             //Here is the problem
                foreach (GridViewRow row in gridActivity.Rows)
                {
                    TextBox txtMon = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtMon");
                    txtMon.Text = mon;
                }
            }            
        }
    }
```

In the below code I can get all the Monday row values and stored into Application["monday"]

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(GridViewRow row in gridActivity.Rows)
        {
            TextBox txtMon = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtMon");
            Application["mondayValues"] = txtMon.Text;
            mondayData = new MondayData { MondayValue = txtMon.Text };
            listMonday.Add(txtMon.Text);
        }
        Application["mondayValues"] = listMonday;
    }
```

[image: grid]

Comment: - Please share with us the aspx code

Comment: BTW. you shouldn't use the Application[] cache for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that you repeat the write process for each of your data lines for all grid lines. This way your last value will be written into all grid lines.

```
//Here I can get all the values
foreach (string mon in Application["mondayValues"] as List<string>)
{

   foreach (GridViewRow row in gridActivity.Rows)
   {
      // PSEUDO CODE
      // if ( row.Text != null )
      // next row
      // else
      // Fill Row with text and break foreach
   }
}
```

Comment: In if condition row does not contain Text property

Comment: That's why i wrote 'pseudo code' . Just wanted to give you the idea how to solve it